# Unable to write to pdf using iText

Tags: java, itext

I have a script that reads a row in an excel sheet, fills an array list with the contents of each cell in that row, and writes it to a text file. I want to be able to write it to a pdf file (using iText) so that I can include an image in the file as well. The problem is I keep getting an error stating that the document has been closed and "Elements cannot be added" to the document. Here is the relevant code:

```
    public File processFile(File excelWorkbook) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, DocumentException{

    System.out.println("Processing file...");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(excelWorkbook);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    HSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = firstSheet.iterator();
    System.out.println("Please choose output file name.");
    String fName = this.chooseFileName();
    try{
    for(int cntr=1; cntr<=firstSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); cntr++){
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        Row currentRow = firstSheet.getRow(cntr);

        for(int cntr2 = 0; cntr2<currentRow.getLastCellNum(); cntr2++){
            Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(cntr2, Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
            if(currentCell==null){
                //cell doesn't have anything in there
                values.add("-not in excel file-");
                continue;
            }else{
              switch(currentCell.getCellType()){
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    values.add(currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                    double num = currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                    String numString = String.valueOf(num);
                    values.add(numString);
                    break;
              }
            }

        }
        //libF = writeArrayListToFile(values, fName);
        writePDF(values, fName);//the method that writes to pdf
    }

    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("Cell is null.");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
        fileInputStream.close();
        return libF;
}
```

Here is the writePDF(ArrayList al, String fName) method:

```
    public void writePDF(ArrayList<String> al, String filepath) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException{
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filepath));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Library"));
    for(String i: al){
        document.add(new Phrase(i+"\n"));
    }
    document.close();
}
```

Why am I not able to write to this file continuously? If I write to a text file, I can close it and open it again easily, so I can get all the information from the excel spreadsheet into a text file. The same does not seem to apply to a pdf file. It is unable to open and close easily. Can someone tell me how I should modify my code? All I want is for the script to read the Row in the excel sheet, add the Cell contents to the array list, and add the array list immediately after that to the pdf document. It just needs to do this for every row. This works for a text file but not for a pdf.

Comment: You are comparing a PDF file to a text file? PDF is totally different. Please start reading https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc/ (it's unfinished but it's free).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are writing every *row* into a pdf document

your writePDF function has a field:

```
document
```

which isn't initialized around file opening (instead i think it's initialized in construction time)
initialize the document the same time you open the output file

Comment: Figured it out over the weekend and yes this was the problem. Thanks.